# Searchable check box list is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is script i wrote to achive searchable check box list but for some reason it is not acting please help!

It should search Regardless of Case and empty lines should be removed

```
$(function() {
$('#filter').on('keyup', function() {
    alert('h');
    var query = this.value;
    $('.checkboxLabel').each(function(i, elem) {
          if (elem.value.indexOf(query) != -1) {
              $(this).closest('label').show();
          }else{
              $(this).closest('label').hide();
          }
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xHxWt/

UPDATE : Thanks Everyone : Down is the fully working fiddle posted it if anyone needs the same

http://jsfiddle.net/xHxWt/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the jQuery plugin (which you already found out).
Also, a `label` doesn't have a value, you need to use `.text()` instead.

Try:

```
$(function () {
    $('#filter').on('keyup', function () {
        var query = this.value;
        $('.checkboxLabel').each(function (i, elem) {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf(query) != -1) {
                $(this).show();
                $(this).prev(':checkbox').show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).prev(':checkbox').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHxWt/8/)

Update:

Hide / show `checkbox` as well.

Comment: Thanks how do i remove unmatched check box along with <br> ? Keeping the constraint that structure of html cant be changed since it is autogenerated!

Comment: See my update: It hides / shows the checkbox as well.

Comment: Thanks alot i would like to ask you one more thing!! would you mind answering it??

Comment: What is it your want to ask?

Comment: if `checkboxLabel` is child div of `mydiv` how can i iterate it? coz there are many divs like `checkboxLabel` which are colliding now??

Comment: You could do `$('#mydiv .checkboxLabel')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to hide label as well as checkbox

```
 $(function() {
        $('#filter').on('keyup', function() {

            var query = this.value;
            $('.checkboxLabel').each(function(i, elem) {
 if ($(this).text().indexOf(query) != -1) {
$(this).closest('label').show();
$(this).prev().show();

                } else {
$(this).closest('label').hide();
$(this).prev().hide();
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

There is also plugin for multiple selection or single.you can try this one also.
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/